# Get web render with search query using phantomjs

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, phantomjs

How to get web content data with search query string, specially on tokopedia.
Below script is working for ebay and amazon but not for tokopedia.
please try to change the url with ebay or amazon to test

```
var page = new WebPage();
var fs = require('fs');
page.onLoadFinished = function() {
  console.log("page load finished");
  page.render('export.png');
  fs.write('1.html', page.content, 'w');
  phantom.exit();
};
page.open("https://www.tokopedia.com/search?st=product&q=handphone", 
  function() {
    page.evaluate(function(){
    });
  });
```

Comment: It sure works for me? What phantomjs version do you have?

Comment: Thanks for replying. I use newest version 2.1. are you sure its work?, are all data loaded?, could you please show captured image. the problem is i cant get the search result. its look like phantomjs capture the web before all script loaded